# jQuery | How to get selected items from select html element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a select option constrols set in my page, that look like the following:

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="name[]" id="ListId">
    <optgroup label="Group 1">
        <optgroup label="Group 1.1">
            <option selected="selected" value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="3">Three</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Group 1.2">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option value="2">Two</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="3">Three</option>
        </optgroup>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Group 2">
        <optgroup label="Group 2.1">
            <option value="1">One</option>
            <option selected="selected" value="2">Two</option>
            <optionvalue="3">Three</option>
        </optgroup>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

By using jQuery when I load my page I try to get the selected items by the code that following:

```
if($('#ListId').length > 0)
{
    var selected = [];

    $('#ListId option[selected="selected"]').each(
        function(i)
        {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var txt = $(this).text();

            selected[val] =   txt;
        }
    );
}
```

Then I modify the above code in order to get the selected items, in the case that the user has make a new selection as following:

```
if($('#ListId').length > 0)
{
    var selected = [];

    $('#ListId option[selected="selected"]').each(
        function(i)
        {
            var val = $(this).val();
            var txt = $(this).text();

            selected[val] =   txt;
        }
    );

    $('#ListId').change(
        function()
        {
            selected = [];

            $('#ListId option[selected="selected"]').each(
                function(i)
                {
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    var txt = $(this).text();

                    selected[val] =   txt;
                }
            );
        }
    );
}
```

But the issue is that still continue reading the previews "selected" items.

You can also visit the fiddle here for live tests : http://jsfiddle.net/Qem7n/

Any idea on how to solve that issue ?

Comment: jsfiddle link is wrong

Comment: You got to save the fiddle and share that :-)

Comment: Ok, I fixed the wrong link. :) Sorry for the wrong link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

change

```
$('#ListId option[selected="selected"]')
```

to

```
$('#ListId option:selected')
```

because: `[selected="selected"]` is not a live selector.

example: http://jsfiddle.net/9YrY8/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/jxQuU/52/

```
function put(sel,i) {
    sel[i.value]=$(i).text();
}
function change() {
    var sel = [];
    $('#ListId option:selected').each(function (k,i){put(sel,i);});
    alert(sel[1]);
}
$('#ListId').on('change',change);
change();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('#ListId').change(function(){
  var selected = $('#ListId').val()
  var str = '';
  for (var i=0;i<selected.length;i++){
    if (i>0) str += ', ';
      str += selected[i];
    }
  alert(str);
});
```

or this:

```
$('#ListId').change(function(){
    var $selected = $('#ListId option:selected');
    var i=0;
    var str = '';
    $selected.each(function(){
    if (i>0) str+= ', ';
    str += $(this).val() + " : " + $(this).text()+ " ";
    ++i;
  });
  alert(str);
});
```

or if you want to put the selected items in an array use this:

```
$('#ListId').change(function(){
  var arr = [];
  var $selected = $('#ListId option:selected');
  //var i=0;
  //var str = '';
  $selected.each(function(){
     //if (i>0) str+= ', ';
     //str += $(this).val() + " : " + $(this).text()+ " ";
     arr[$(this).val()+$(this).parent().prop('label')] = $(this).text();
     //++i;
  });
  console.log(arr);
});
```

you should take into consideration that you have the same value for options and using the option value as an index of your array will cause other values on your array with same index value to be changed and not appended to your array.

Answer (score 2):

There's a one line solution to it, just use this

```
$('#formid').find('select[name="selectname"]').val()
```

it should work, it did for me!

Answer (score 2):

same as that thomas said, you can use too

```
$('option:selected', '#ListId')
```

the second param represents the scope of the search